# Andorid Studio: ExecutionException : (integer) -1 is less than minimum integer 0

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to Android Studio 3 Canary build 2, which bumped up my build tools like so:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
```

Now when I try to build I get this issue:

```
Error:.../values.xml:3490 (integer) -1 is less than minimum integer 0
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingResources'.
Failed to execute aapt
```

So I took a look at line 3490 of the file referenced above and got this:

```
<item name="android:numColumns">auto_fit</item>
```

Because it references I GridView style, I went to the docs and found that [AUTO_FIT has a value of -1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#AUTO_FIT)

I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue but I've tried cleaning/building, restarting and I still get that issue. Any idea what to try?

Comment: I ran into the same thing, watch updates here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62358540

Comment: Depending on your case you may override the value with a number greater than -1. In my case the number of columns is used by month picker in Braintree. That looks good with 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable AAPT2 by putting this in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your build tools to 26.0.2 or newer, it was a bug in AAPT2, it should be fixed now.
If you're still using an alpha or a beta of AndroidStudio try upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.